# php not following functions structure

Tags: php, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Having trouble with functions structure not following (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542821/having-trouble-with-functions-structure-not-following-php)

**Problem :** Every time I am submitting the `answerSubmit` button, instead of displaying the echo `student answers` in the the `StudentAnswers()` function, it goes back up to the `pickSession()` function.

I have a demo here you can use to see what is happening: [DEMO](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text30.php)

When you open demo, select an assessment from assessment (session) drop down menu. You will see another 2 drop down menus `students` and `questions` drop down menu appear. Now if you click on the `answerSubmit` button (`Get Students Answers` button), then it should display echo stating `student answers`, but instead you can see it goes back to only displaying the assessment drop down menu. Why is this?

Below is the code for the demo:

```
function PickSession()
    {

//mysqli code retreiving data for options in assessments drop down menu goes here ....  

        ?>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"> 
            <p>
            <strong>Asessments:</strong>
            <select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <?php
                    while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
                        $sv = $dbSessionId;
                        if(isset($_POST["session"]) && $sv == $_POST["session"]) 
                            echo "<option selected='selected' value='$sv'>" .
                                  $dbSessionName .
                                  " - " .
                                  date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dbSessionDate)) .
                                  " - " . 
                                  date('H:i',strtotime($dbSessionTime)) .
                                 "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                        else
                            echo "<option value='$sv'>" .
                                  $dbSessionName . 
                                  " - " . 
                                  date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dbSessionDate)) . 
                                  " - " .
                                  date('H:i',strtotime($dbSessionTime)) .
                                  "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            </p>
            <input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Assessments" name="sessionSubmit" />
        </form>
    <?php
    }

    function SessionIsSubmitted()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['sessionSubmit'])) // we have subbmited the second form
        {
            if(empty($_POST["session"])) // We picked the "Please select" option
            { ?>
                    Please Select an Assessment

            <?php 
                return false;
            }
            else // All is ok
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    function ShowAssessment()
    {   

//mysqli code retreiving data for options in students drop down menu goes here ....  

    if($studentnum == 0){ ?>

    There are no Students who have currently taken this Assessment

    <?php } else { 


//mysqli code retreiving data for options in questions drop down menu goes here .... 

            ?>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">         
    <p>
    <strong>Student:</strong>
    <select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <?php
    while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {
    $stu = $dbStudentId;
    if(isset($_POST["student"]) && $stu == $_POST["student"]) 
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$stu'>" .
             $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " .
             $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo "<option value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . 
              $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . 
              "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p>
    <strong>Question:</strong>
    <select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <?php
    while ( $questionsstmt->fetch() ) {
    $ques = $dbQuestionId;
    if(isset($_POST["question"]) && $ques == $_POST["question"]) 
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$ques'>" . 
              $dbQuestionNo . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo "<option value='$ques'>" . $dbQuestionNo . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </p>

    <input id="answerSubmit" type="submit" value="Get Student's Answers" name="answerSubmit" />
    </form>

    <?php
    }
    }

    function StudentAnswersIsSubmitted()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['answerSubmit'])) // we have subbmited the second form
        {

        return false;

        }
        return false;
    }

    function StudentAnswers()
    {

    echo "student answers";

    }

    ?>
```

...

```
 <body>


    <?php


            PickSession(); // Show the thing to pick session
            if(SessionIsSubmitted()) // When session is picked
            {
              ShowAssessment(); // Show students and questions information
              if(StudentAnswersIsSubmitted()) // Student Answers button is submitted
                {
                  StudentAnswers();
                }

            }



    ?>


    </body>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
function PickSession()
    {

//mysqli code retreiving data for options in assessments drop down menu goes here ....  

        ?>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"> 
               <p>
            <strong>Asessments:</strong>
            <select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <?php
                    while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
                        $sv = $dbSessionId;
                        if(isset($_POST["session"]) && $sv == $_POST["session"]) 
                            echo "<option selected='selected' value='$sv'>" . $dbSessionName . " - " . date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dbSessionDate)) . " - " . date('H:i',strtotime($dbSessionTime)) . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                        else
                            echo "<option value='$sv'>" . $dbSessionName . " - " . date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dbSessionDate)) . " - " . date('H:i',strtotime($dbSessionTime)) . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            </p>
            <input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Assessments" name="sessionSubmit" />
        </form>
    <?php
    }


function SessionIsSubmitted()
{
        if(isset($_POST["session"]) && empty($_POST["session"])) // We picked the "Please select" option
        { ?>
            <div class="red">
                Please Select an Assessment
            </div>
        <?php 
            return false;
        }
    else if(!isset($_POST["session"]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else // All is ok
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}


    function ShowAssessment()
    {   

//mysqli code retreiving data for options in students drop down menu goes here ....  

    if($studentnum == 0){ ?>

    There are no Students who have currently taken this Assessment

    <?php } else { 


//mysqli code retreiving data for options in questions drop down menu goes here .... 

            ?>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">         
    <p>
    <input type="text" name="session" value="<?php echo $_POST['session']; ?>">
    <strong>Student:</strong>
    <select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <?php
    while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {
    $stu = $dbStudentId;
    if(isset($_POST["student"]) && $stu == $_POST["student"]) 
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo "<option value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p>
    <strong>Question:</strong>
    <select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <?php
    while ( $questionsstmt->fetch() ) {
    $ques = $dbQuestionId;
    if(isset($_POST["question"]) && $ques == $_POST["question"]) 
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$ques'>" . $dbQuestionNo . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo "<option value='$ques'>" . $dbQuestionNo . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </p>

    <input id="answerSubmit" type="submit" value="Get Student's Answers" name="answerSubmit" />
    </form>

    <?php
    }
    }

function StudentAnswersIsSubmitted()
{

if(!isset($_POST["answerSubmit"]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else // All is ok
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

    ?>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

HERE IS DEMO FOR CODE BELOW: [DEMO](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text29.php)

```
function PickModule()
{ ?>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"> 
        <?php            
        $moduleactive = 1;

        $sql = "SELECT ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleActive = ? ORDER BY ModuleNo"; 

        //mysqli code for modules drop down menu

        ?>
        <strong>Module:</strong>
        <select name="module" id="modulesDrop">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <?php
            while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
                $ov = $dbModuleNo . "_" . $dbModuleName . "_" . $dbModuleId; 
                if(isset($_POST["module"]) && $ov == $_POST["module"]) 
                    echo "<option selected='selected' value='$ov'>$dbModuleNo - $dbModuleName</option>" . PHP_EOL; 
                else 
                    echo "<option value='$ov'>$dbModuleNo - $dbModuleName</option>" . PHP_EOL;
             } 
            ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" />
    </form>
<?php }
function ModuleIsSubmitted()
{
    if(isset($_POST["module"]) && empty($_POST["module"])) // We picked the "Please select" option
    { ?>
            Please Select a Module
    <?php 
        return false;
    }
    else if(!isset($_POST["module"]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else // All is ok
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
function PickSession()
{

    $dataTransfered = explode( "_" , $_POST["module"] );
    $moduleNo = $dataTransfered[0];
    $moduleName = $dataTransfered[1];
    $moduleId = $dataTransfered[2];

    //Get data from database
    $sessionquery = "
        SELECT s.SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId, SessionActive, Complete
        FROM Session s
        INNER JOIN Session_Complete sc ON sc.SessionId = s.SessionId
        WHERE
        (ModuleId = ? AND Complete = ?)
        ORDER BY SessionName 
        ";
    $complete = 1;

//mysqli code for assessments drop down menu  

    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="module" value="<?php echo $_POST['module']; ?>">
        <p>
            <strong>Selected Module: </strong><?php echo $moduleNo ." - ". $moduleName; ?> 
        </p>
    <?php if ($sessionnum == 0 ){ ?>
        <div class="red">
            Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
           <p>
        <strong>Asessments:</strong>
        <select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <?php
                while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
                    $sv = $dbSessionId;
                    if($dbSessionActive == 0){
                        $class = 'red';
                    }else{
                        $class = 'green';   
                    }
                    if(isset($_POST["session"]) && $sv == $_POST["session"]) 
                        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$sv' class='$class'>" . $dbSessionName . " - " . date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dbSessionDate)) . " - " . date('H:i',strtotime($dbSessionTime)) . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                    else
                        echo "<option value='$sv' class='$class'>" . $dbSessionName . " - " . date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dbSessionDate)) . " - " . date('H:i',strtotime($dbSessionTime)) . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        </p>
        <input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Assessments" name="sessionSubmit" />
    </form>
<?php
}
}
function SessionIsSubmitted()
{
        if(isset($_POST["session"]) && empty($_POST["session"])) // We picked the "Please select" option
        { ?>
            <div class="red">
                Please Select an Assessment
            </div>
        <?php 
            return false;
        }
    else if(!isset($_POST["session"]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else // All is ok
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}


function ShowAssessment()
{   

$studentactive = 1;

$currentstudentqry = "
SELECT
st.StudentId, st.StudentAlias, st.StudentForename, st.StudentSurname
FROM
Student_Session ss 
INNER JOIN
Student st ON ss.StudentId = st.StudentId
WHERE
(ss.SessionId = ? AND st.Active = ?)
ORDER BY st.StudentAlias
";

//mysqli code for students drop down menu


if($studentnum == 0){ ?>

<div class="red">
There are no Students who have currently taken this Assessment
</div>
<?php } else { 

$questionsqry = "
SELECT
QuestionId, QuestionNo
FROM
Question
WHERE
(SessionId = ?)
ORDER BY QuestionNo
";

//mysqli code for questions drop down menu

        ?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">         
<p>
<input type="text" name="session" value="<?php echo $_POST['session']; ?>">
<strong>Student:</strong>
<select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
<option value="All">All</option>
<?php
while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {
$stu = $dbStudentId;
if(isset($_POST["student"]) && $stu == $_POST["student"]) 
    echo "<option selected='selected' value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo "<option value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Question:</strong>
<select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
<option value="All">All</option>
<?php
while ( $questionsstmt->fetch() ) {
$ques = $dbQuestionId;
if(isset($_POST["question"]) && $ques == $_POST["question"]) 
    echo "<option selected='selected' value='$ques'>" . $dbQuestionNo . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo "<option value='$ques'>" . $dbQuestionNo . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</select>
</p>

<input id="answerSubmit" type="submit" value="Get Student's Answers" name="answerSubmit" />
</form>

<?php
}
}

function StudentAnswersIsSubmitted()
{

if(!isset($_POST["answerSubmit"]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else // All is ok
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

function StudentAnswers()
{

echo "student answers";

}

?>
```

.......

```
<?php


    PickModule(); // Show the thing to pick module

    if(ModuleIsSubmitted()) // When module is picked
    {
        PickSession(); // Show the thing to pick session
        if(SessionIsSubmitted()) // When session is picked
        {
          ShowAssessment(); // Show students and questions information
          if(StudentAnswersIsSubmitted()) // Student Answers button is submitted
            {
              StudentAnswers();
            }

        }

    }



?>
```

Comment: I don't see a `pickModules()` function defined (or used) in your question code.

Comment: Don't you get bored with repeating every your question [many times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14542821/285587)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I meant pickSession(), bot pickModules() sorry

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the second form, the `SessionIsSubmitted` function doesn't pass because the second form on your page doesn't contain the information needed (sessionSubmit). The `sessionSubmit` is inside of the first form only and therefore does not get submitted.

You need to have something in your second form that allows you to pass the first form test

Comment: I have provided an update, it is still doing same thing but can you see where the problem is? I included a text input showing value of assessment (session) chosen above student drop down menu and I changed the `SessionisSubmitted()` and `StudentAnswersSubmitted()` function

Comment: Can't see why it's not working, the demo was not updated so it's a little more difficult. I would echo out in your SessionIsSubmitted if else statement to see if session is getting returned at all.

Comment: I will update demo, and provide an echo where you mentioned

Comment: IT actually works in demo, but not is real application. but the difference in the real application is that there is an extra functions before submitting assessment, let me update code so you can see and I will provide another demo on this. Give me 15 -20 mins

Comment: Ok I included an `UPDATE 2 section` which shows you demo where it contains all drop down menus. In this demo the only difference is that it contains an extra drop down menu known as `Modules` at the start of the page. You can see it working in original demo link where the modules drop down menu was not included btw